# How to calculate average of 5 student mark, and implement that in datatable.js, how to do this?

Tags: javascript

This is my json data

```
var myList = [
    [1, "Karthick", 90, 95, 85, 95, 100,],
    [2, "Ram", 98, 90, 95, 95, 100],
    [3, "Suthan", 80, 90, 85, 100, 95],
    [4, "Ganesh", 90, 100, 100, 99, 96],
    [5, "Thilak", 98, 99, 99, 100, 100],
    [6, "Mari",90, 100, 100, 99, 100]
]; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' ); 
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": myList,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Id" },
            { "title": "Name" },
            { "title": "Mark1" },
            { "title": "Mark2"},
            { "title": "Mark3"},
            { "title": "Mark4"},
            { "title": "Mark5"},
            { "title": "Average"},
            { "title": "Grade"}
        ]
    });   
});
```

I send those json data in to datatable.js, but my doubt is how to calculate the average of 5 marks and show that average mark in datatable using datatable.js

Comment: I'd just stick a bit of code in the `ready`before the datatable is initiated, to calculate the data & stick it in the object. Once done you can just use it like any other column in the datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this before the `('#example').dataTable(`

```
 for(var i in myList){
      // Assuming they are all out of 100
       var avg = (( myList[i][2]+myList[i][3]+myList[i][4]+myList[i][5]+myList[i][6] ) / 5);
      // add avg to array
      myList[i].push(avg);
      // add grade
      myList[i].push("Some logic to put number here");
 }
```

Basically all the above would do is calculate the avg (and the grade with whatever logic), then stick the info on the end of the array items in myList, ready to be passed straight in to the dataTable.

Edit: see working example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w5bqxops/1/

FYI: seems your also missing a closing `});` for the jquery ready :)

Comment: Hi Carl, thanks for your help its working perfectly. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the soln.

```
var myList = [
    [1, "Karthick", 90, 95, 85, 95, 100,],
    [2, "Ram", 98, 90, 95, 95, 100],
    [3, "Suthan", 80, 90, 85, 100, 95],
    [4, "Ganesh", 90, 100, 100, 99, 96],
    [5, "Thilak", 98, 99, 99, 100, 100],
    [6, "Mari",90, 100, 100, 99, 100]
]; 

   function avg( ){
    var i, av = 0;
    for (i = 2, len = this.length ; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(!isNaN(this[i]))
        av += this[i];
    }
    return av;
}
Array.prototype.avg = avg; 

    myList.map(function(array){
    array[array.length-1] = array.avg();
          return array;
    });
```